# Error on grpc-java gradle build

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I am getting the attached error on building the `grpc-java` (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/) examples. I have `gradle.properties` file in `grpc-java\examples` folder that has one property , which is `skipCodegen=true`

```
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples>gradlew build --stacktrace
:extractIncludeProto UP-TO-DATE
:extractProto UP-TO-DATE
:generateProto UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:299: error: illegal character: '\u2020'
      double ╧å1 = toRadians(lat1);
              ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:300: error: illegal character: '\u2020'
      double ╧å2 = toRadians(lat2);
              ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:301: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
      double ╬ö╧å = toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
              ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:301: error: illegal character: '\u2020'
      double ╬ö╧å = toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
                ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:301: error: not a statement
      double ╬ö╧å = toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
               ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:302: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
      double ╬ö╬╗ = toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
              ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:302: error: illegal character: '\u00bb'
      double ╬ö╬╗ = toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
                ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:302: error: not a statement
      double ╬ö╬╗ = toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
               ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                      ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: illegal character: '\u2020'
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                        ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: not a statement
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                       ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                                      ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: illegal character: '\u2020'
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                                        ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: not a statement
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                                       ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: illegal character: '\u2020'
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                                                      ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: not a statement
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                                                       ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: ';' expected
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                                                        ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: illegal character: '\u2020'
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                                                                 ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: not a statement
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                                                                  ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: ';' expected
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                                                                   ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                                                                            ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: illegal character: '\u00bb'
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                                                                              ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: not a statement
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                                                                             ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                                                                                            ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: illegal character: '\u00bb'
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                                                                                              ^
C:\gRPC\grpc-java\examples\src\main\java\io\grpc\examples\routeguide\RouteGuideServer.java:304: error: not a statement
      double a = sin(╬ö╧å / 2) * sin(╬ö╧å / 2) + cos(╧å1) * cos(╧å2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2) * sin(╬ö╬╗ / 2);
                                                                                             ^
26 errors
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:241)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:214)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:207)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:48)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:104)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:163)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:145)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 60 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.853 secs
```

Answer (score 1):

@ejona86  and @carl-mastrangelo  , thanks for your help,

Setting the following two successfully helped solve the issue

`gradle.properties` = `compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'`
`pom.xml`= `<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`

I am able to compile in Gradle and Maven

The same answer is in https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2394